# How to print specific number of words from a string in scala?

Tags: string, scala

I have a strings:

```
str = "this is a great place...."
```

I want to print only 30 words from this string. How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `split` and `take` methods:

```
val str = "this is a great place...."
str.split("\\W").take(30).mkString(" ")
// res0: String = this is a great place
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do something like:

```
"""(\b\w+\b\W*){0,30}""".r findPrefixOf "this is a great place...."
```

Or using a different notation:

```
"""(\b\w+\b\W*){0,30}""".r.findPrefixOf("this is a great place....")
```

Comment: When I f.write("""(\b\w*\b\W*){0,30}""".r findPrefixOf "this is a great place...."), I get an error! Some multiple markers error!!

Comment: @LindaSu I'm not a mindreader. I have no idea what `f.write` is and even less of an idea what "some multiple markers" error means. My code executes in the Scala REPL. How you further wish to integrate it in your application is completely unknown to me since you provide virtually no information in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just trying to write it to a file using FileWriter.

Comment: @LindaSu Well, add the relevant code to the question and you'll be sure got get help and avoid further downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code you can work with

1. Split string using the split method into an Array[String] of the words.
2. Iterate across the array and concatenate the words together that you want to include
3. Print out the string

I can't think of any external libraries or built-in functions that will do that for you. You will need to write your own code to do this.